# Mitigating the effects of refactoring code within a git repo

Tags: git, refactoring

I've been using git for a while on a project, and its time to clean up.

I have a few source code files that have become to large and should be split up into multiple files. I also want to move some functions from one file to a more appropriate one.

Since git tracks all my changes, will this effectively double the size of my git repo? Is there a way to avoid this? Or is it a better practice to keep a history of these changes? (in case for some reason I want to go back to the messy state I'm currently in)

Thoughts, opinions and solutions welcome!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all revisions, the size of your git repository will increase with your changes, however, I do not think that this should be something you ultimately worry about too much. I would suggest that it is better to keep the history as you make these changes, not least so that you can undo your actions if something goes wrong, but also it helps anyone else who may be working with your repository either now or in the future to understand what has happened to certain files (if indeed they care to check using `git blame`).

(If you want to modify or "squash" previous revisions together, you can look at using `git-rebase`, but modifying git history often comes with disastrous consequences - I don't advise it, and it certainly isn't for the faint of heart.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether or not you want be able to return to this messy state.  IMHO you should always make sure that you can return to an older state even if that state was a mess.. ya never know what you might refactor incorrectly.

That said, it sounds like repo size is an issue, so you don't want to keep those big files around.  If that's the case, perhaps you can make a tarball of the current working directory, save it off someplace where file size is less of an issue, and run a [filter-branch command](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-a-git-repository) to clean up those big files.

Frankly though, I'd try to find ways to deal with the big repository size.  Keeping everything in git is definitely the cleanest way.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect your repository to grow in such a way. Remember...

> [Git tracks content not files](http://book.git-scm.com/3_normal_workflow.html)

If the volume of your *content* is not expanding hugely, then the volume of your *repository* shouldn't either.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind a couple things about git (or any good version control, really):

1. git stores the difference between files, not actual copies of all of the files
2. under the hood, git will garbage-collect and compress repositories together. For plain text (like program code), that will result in a substantial space savings.

As a completely nonscientific test, I looked at the the closest git repository available (open in another terminal window), which has several weeks of commits in it. The directory as a whole was about twice the size of the .git directory, which means that the repository, all commits, and all metadata are stored in about the same amount of space as the files that make up the current working directory.

In short, refactor away, you probably don't need to worry about the disk space. I am SURE it won't double the size.

Comment: Point 1 is actually wrong -- git keeps files, not deltas.  (This makes it quite different from many older SCMs which kept forward deltas, like original SCCS, or reverse deltas, like RCS, or "interleaved" deltas, like later SCCS.)  However, it also keeps its contents in compressed binary form, so if a big chunk of code is the same in fileA and fileB even though fileA and fileB are different (and even in different branches and so on), the compression helps a lot.

Comment: I did not know that. You're right, that's a departure from almost every other SCM. I believe my point still stands, though, that the repository size gain from moving a chunk of code from one text file to another is negligible, since it will eventually be compressed away to nearly nothing.